# How to align buttons in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with two large buttons but  when they are large there are no spacing between buttons and too much spacing when they are  normal.  What's the trick for aligning them appropriately?.  When resized, I would like them to be either next to search input or centered in the next row.

[image]

Here is my code

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Find Something">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search 1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search 2</button>      
          </div>
        </div>        
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about forgetting about `.col-xx-XX` and use `.form-inline` instead ? (doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline))

You would end with this code :

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Find Something" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search 1</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search 2</button>            
    </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4895/).